# How to demostraste that some point places in the center of a triangle (see image below)?

Tags: vectors

Given this:
[image]

How to demonstrate that: $\frac{u}{3} + \frac{w}{3} + \frac{v}{3}$ is the center of the triangle between u, v, and w.

Comment: What is the "*center of the triangle*" definition you are using? Two common definitions of the centroid are $g = \frac{1}{3}(u+v+w)$ or $(u-g)+(v-g)+(w-g)=0$, both equivalent to the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

The midpoint of the side facing point $u$ is

$m_u = \frac{1}{2} (v + w) $

and similarly,

$m_v = \frac{1}{2} (u + w) $ and $m_w = \frac{1}{2} (u + v) $

The line segment from $u$ to $m_u$ has the parametric equation

$ P_u = u + t (m_u - u) = (1 - t) u + t m_u = (1 - t) + \frac{1}{2} t (v + w) $

Similarly, the line segments between $v$ , $m_v$ and $w$, $m_w$ are given by

$ P_v = (1 - s) v + \frac{1}{2}s (u+w) $ , and $ P_w = (1 - r) w + \frac{1}{2}r (u + v) $

where $t, s, r \in [0, 1] $

The center of the triangle is the point that is the intersection of the three line segments.  It is seen by setting $t = s = r = \frac{2}{3} $ that

$P_u = P_v = P_w = \frac{1}{3} (u + v + w ) $

Therefore, this is the expression for the center.